# list comprehension structure equivalent for loop example

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

i tried to replicate the for loop example to list comprehension to get the same output without successes.

```
TS = [[[1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8]], [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]], [[3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3]]]

TSF=[]
for i in TS:
    F=[]
    for j in i:
        for e in j:
            F.append(e)
    TSF.append(F) 

print TSF
[[1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Help is very welcome

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Comment: yes, but you mention "I tried", then you can at least provide your (failed) attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example with the same label

```
[[e for j in i for e in j] for i in TS]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use `chain` from `itertools`:

```
[list(chain(*i)) for i in TS]
```

**Demo:**

```
from itertools import chain
TS=[[[1,2],[3,4]]]
TSF=[list(chain(*i)) for i in TS]
```

Or as with `from_iterable`:

```
[list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in TS]
```

**Demo:**

```
from itertools import chain
TS=[[[1,2],[3,4]]]
TSF=[list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in TS]
```

Or `functools.reduce`:

```
[functools.reduce(operator.concat, i) for i in TS]
```

**Demo:**

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import concat
TS=[[[1,2],[3,4]]]
TSF=[reduce(concat,i) for i in TS]
```

Or Numpy:

```
[list(numpy.array(i).flat) for i in TS]
```

**Demo:**

```
import numpy as np
TS=[[[1,2],[3,4]]]
TSF=[list(np.array(i).flat) for i in TS]
```

Or Numpy again:

```
[list(np.concatenate(i)) for i in TS]
```

**Demo:**

```
import numpy as np
TS=[[[1,2],[3,4]]]
TSF=[list(np.concatenate(i)) for i in TS]
```

For all cases:

```
print(TSF)
```

Is as expected:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following list comprehension to flatten the inner lists:

```
[[i for s in l for i in s] for l in TS]
```

so that given `TS = [[[1,2,3],[2]],[[2,3]]]`, this (and your `TSF`) returns:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code should get a list of list for you:

```
[[e for j in i for e in j] for i in TS]
```